# What is colord-sane and why does it show up on lsof internet watch?

Tags: internet-connection

My friend is using 12.10 and noticed how the command "colord-sane" shows up on lsof every time he plugs in or unplugs a usb-stick. I tried the same thing on 12.04 (what I use) and colord-sane does not show up.

What is colord-sane? Why is it showing up on 12.10? If it doesn't need internet access why is it even showing up at all on the lsof watch? How would my friend go about stopping it from trying to get on internet if it was something he wanted to stop?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Let me guess: your friend's PC has an IP-address 192.168.1.9 and he is using some device with a "color-profile" (like a scanner, color-printer,...).

Comment: Yes, that is his IP (he has a router). He installed Xsane but has not installed any scanner or printer drivers. And he has not installed a color profile (ie, system settings > color). Doesn't anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 1):

colord is a system service that makes it easy to manage, install and generate color profiles to accurately color manage input and output devices.

It does a lot of things and is deep integrated into the system, see http://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/intro.html

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question. The question is "why" not "what does colord do".

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: It answers the first part: What is colord-sane?