# Multicast packets sent out every time a USB device is connected

Tags: usb, input-devices, sane

On Ubuntu 22.04, every time a USB device is connected to the computer, the system sends IGMP and WS-Discovery packets on the network. More specifically, on a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04, connecting any USB stick or USB mouse will trigger the sending of:

- IGMP packet to the multicast IP address 224.0.0.22
- WS-Discovery (port 3702) packets over UDP/IPv4 and UDP/IPv6, respectively to 239.255.255.250 or ff02::c, packets which are sent out by colord-sane

This is probably similar to the issue previously mentioned here: [What is colord-sane and why does it show up on lsof internet watch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247182/what-is-colord-sane-and-why-does-it-show-up-on-lsof-internet-watch)

What would be expected:

- No network traffic to be generated for local-only USB devices
- No SANE-related sub-requests (e.g., no color profile adjustment attempts from colord) when the USB device is not a scanner

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/colord/intro.html

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The data that wireshark captures when a usb inserted: 239.255.255.250   UDP 649 44274 → 3702 Len=607:

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probeurn:uuid:d297b7d4-5d58-bbcc-688a-c52c44fd2d61urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discoverywsdp:Device

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the question?